# How to get average of elements along columns or rows in an ojAlgo matrix?

Tags: java, matrix, average, linear-algebra, ojalgo

Is there a way to compute the average of the primitive elements along the columns or rows of a matrix, such that we obtain vectors with the average values?

For example, let

```
A = [[1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6]]
```

be a `2x3` matrix.  The column-wise average would be retrieved in a 3-element vector, like `[2.5, 3.5, 4.5]`, while the row-wise average would be retrieved in a 2-element vector, like `[2, 5]`.

Numpy and Matlab offer this functionality, and I was wondering if there is such availability in ojAlgo.  This, of course, would preclude the use of loops, which is desired in our case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, currently you have to do some looping yourself, but please open an issue for this at GitHub.

https://github.com/optimatika/ojAlgo/issues

(It will be implemented.)

Comment: Now it is implemented.